# LINQ union with optional null second parameter

Tags: c#, linq, union

I have two queries which return a collection of the same kind of object, after these two queries are done, I want to union them.

```
var results = from t in All()
              where t.Blah.Contains(blahblah)
              select t;

var results2 = from t in All()
               where t.blah2.contains(blahblah)
               select t;

return results.Union(results2);
```

It is *possible* that the second query could return no results, and be `null`.

It seems like if I try and perform a union with the two, if the second argument is null it will throw an `ArgumentNullException`.

The obvious answer would be to just to perform `.ToList()` on the second query to see if it contains anything. The problem with this is I am trying to take advantage of deferred execution and dont want to actually perform the query on the database at this stage.

Is there any way around this?

Edit - Solution

```
var results2 = from t in All()
        where t.blah2!=null && t.blah2.Contains(blahblah)
        select t;
```

Basically, the actual query was returning null as I was trying to do a contains on a null list

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure that there's any advantage to deferred execution in this case, as you will *always* need to know if result2 contains one or more record. $0.02

Comment: thanks for the edit Ani, not sure what is going on with my browser :/ @Ian P - I want to basically stuff it all into one list and then later I may want to do some additional filtering before I toList it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`results2` should return an empty list and not `null` when executing its query.  The code you have should not cause any problems and should work just fine in all cases simple cases I can think of.  Can you provide input which would cause the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I would think that too, but it is null for some reason. I just effectively did Ian P's answer and on the count check it is throwing a NullReferenceException. I guess something else must be wrong..

Comment: @qui then the most likely answer is that your function `All()` is returning null.  You can step through the debugger to verify that.

Comment: Ok, after fixing some other rudamentry bugs, I have checked and my All() function definitely isn't returning null. Yet, the expression on results 2 is throwing a NullRef exception. Any ideas? :/

Comment: an instance of `t` or `t.blah2` is null or `blahblah` is null and `t.blah2.contains()` is unwilling to accept a null

Comment: @NickLarsen - I think you've got it.

Comment: Just for everyone's amusement, this caused quite a moment of FUUUUUU for me - http://yfrog.com/gzz2gp

Comment: Marked as the answer, as it was essentially correct and put me in the right direction. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 7):

Would the following not solve your problem?

```
return from t in All()
       where t.Blah.Contains(blahblah) && t.Blah2.Contains(blahblah)
       select t;
```

However, if `results` and `results2` need to remain separate and you want to combine them:

```
return results.Union(results2 ?? Enumerable.Empty<TResult>());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = from t in All()
           where t.Blah.Contains(blahblah)
            select t;

var results2 = from t in All()
           where t.blah2.contains(blahblah)
             select t;

return (results2 != null || results2.Count() > 0) ? results.Union(results2) : results;
```

This will either return the union if there is something in results2, or just return the first result set.